# Submission error messages should not disappear when entered on field level

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

I am using `redux` form in my project. I have few input fields, a drop down and a submit button. When I click on a submit button, submission errors are displayed.

For example, I have an input field which can accept integers only. When I click on the submit button, an error message is displayed: "please enter integers only." But when I edit the input field and place the correct value, the error message is removed from submission errors without clicking on the submit button.

I don't want to remove error messages without clicking on the submit button.

Is there any property in `redux` form?

Answer (score 0):

Onchange of input field and onclick of submit button are two different events. You can check the validity only on submit event.